# How to show $|\sin(2x)-\sin(2a)|$ is bounded by $2|\sin(x-a)|$?

Tags: real-analysis, trigonometry

I came across a problem in section 3.4 on uniform continuity in Wade's 4th ed Introduction to Analysis. The exercise is just to apply the definition of uniform continuity to $f(x)=x\sin(2x)$ on $x\in(0,1)$.

The function is clearly uniformly continuous, which I don't have any problem showing. But I wanted to check on a step from the solution manual where there is an interesting global bound given: $|\sin(2x)-\sin(2a)|\leq 2|\sin(x-a)|$.

It is not stated as a global bound, but it seems to be one. I am able to derive it as a bound on $(0,1)$, but my sequence of steps seems too complicated for a basic undergrad advanced calc exercise.

My questions: Is this a well-known bound that most undergrads should have encountered? What is the quickest way to derive the bound, both globally and on $(0,1)$?

Here is my method for $(0,1)$. Assume $x,a\in(0,1)$ and $x>a$.

$$\begin{aligned}
|x\sin(2x)-a\sin(2a)|
&\leq|x\sin(2x)-x\sin(2a)| \qquad &\text{ (since $x>a$) }\\
&\leq|\sin(2x)-\sin(2a)| \qquad &\text{ (since $0<x<1$) }\\
&=|2\sin(x)\cos(x)-2\sin(a)\cos(a)| \qquad &\text{ (double angle identity) }\\
&\leq2|\sin(x)\cos(x)-\sin(a)\cos(x)| \qquad &\text{ ($x>a$ & $\cos$ decr.) }\\
&\leq2|\sin(x)\cos(a)-\sin(a)\cos(x)| \qquad &\text{ ($x>a$ & $\cos$ decr.) }\\
&=2|\sin(x-a)| \qquad &\text{ (angle difference identity) }\\
\end{aligned}$$

This argument uses the fact that $x,a\in(0,1)$ when I use the fact that $\cos(x)$ is decreasing on that interval and allows us to swap $\cos(x)$ and $\cos(a)$ in lines 4 and 5 in the above equation. Is there a quicker way to get from line 2 to line 6? It will need to be elementary, something that an undergrad in a very basic intro to analysis course might know. I suppose it could be the case that a sufficiently complicated argument is required and this just happens to be one of the harder problems.

Comment: Is the title correct?

Comment: @JaideepKhare, Yes, you have to read the question carefully to see so. I knew some confusion would occur though due to the nature of the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint:

$\sin x - \sin y= $

$2 \cos\dfrac {x+y}{2} \sin \dfrac {x-y}{2}.$

Comment: Good old sum-to-product formula... I've never really used those much. I guess I need to commit them to memory. Thanks!

Comment: Jdods.Welcome Was a bit hesitant to post this formulae , could not imagine that you had not come across it.Thought ,  there was a bug somewhere, in your problem, or what not.Just seemed to obvious.Obvious or not , if it helps a bit.These things are in Analysis books. You can look them up.No need to.memorize.:)))

Comment: Very nice Peter, one good way to obtain and prove is from $\sin(a+b)=\sin a \cos b +\sin b \cos a$ $\sin(a-b)=\sin a \cos b -\sin b \cos a$ with $a=(x+y)/2$ and $b=(x-y)/2$.

Comment: Gimusi.Nice proof.Thanks.